# How can I migrate from AOL Mail to GMail?

Tags: gmail, migrate-data, aol-mail

I was able to import contacts but I want to make sure I have a smooth transition and don't lose any mail. I want to make sure if anyone emails me at AOL that it forwards over to Gmail for a period of time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Gmails mail fetcher and AOL's POP3 access;

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=21288

Use your full AOL e-mail address for the username, including the domain

> Server: pop.aol.com
>
> Port  : 995
>
> SSL   : Yes

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [step by step guide](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25413&topic=25415) to import your contacts and mails from supported by Gmail. Hope it helps.